# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup appears to be accessing the wrong page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to grasp web scraping as a small project. I'm trying to access products on a webpage and print out the amount of times they've been sold. My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as req

SEARCH_QUERY = 'swimsuit'

url = f'https://www.aliexpress.com/premium/swimsuit.html?ltype=premium&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText='\
     f'{SEARCH_QUERY}&trafficChannel=ppc&SortType=default&page=2'

original_website = req.get(url)
source = original_website.content
soup = bs(source, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all()
for link in links:
    print(link.get('sale-value'))
```

So, I looked at the website and the information I want is deep within the HTML, under a tag called sale-value. When I run the code, all that gets printed is a sequence of `None`. I believe the scraping is under the wrong webpage, probably the default page. Any help would be appreciated!

Printing the source gives me:

https://pastebin.com/d0w7FLxA

Comment: Try printing the whole source, or saving it to a file.

Comment: Just printed the source, I believe it isn't the webpage I'm looking for but I don't really know how to read it or use it.

Comment: Save it to a pastebin and atttach to the question. Also convert it to the HTML

Comment: Edited, used a website to convert to HTML so I hope that works. Thanks!

Comment: No, you need to print the source before it's parsed. You can't convert the parsed output back to HTML

Comment: When you execute this line `print(original_website.url)`, you will understand that the returned url leads you to the log-in page.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a nagging suspicion it has got to do with AliExpress throwing you out onto the login page every time you try searching for a particular product or typing a query directly into the address bar instead of following the menu links. Perhaps, Selenium would be a better choice for the task