# BeautifulSoup scraping the wrong page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328098/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-appears-to-be-accessing-the-wrong-page) didnt work for me. I am scraping the website slider.kz. But when i scrape the website it pulls the html of the main page instead of the specified url.
My code

```
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
headers = {'user-agent': fake_useragent.UserAgent().random}
soup = BeautifulSoup(get('https://slider.kz/#unravel', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(i.get('href'))
```

The actual output returned:

```
https://twitter.com/x_slider
https://paypal.me/xslider
/
```

What it should return extracted using selenium :

Selenium code used to extract the desired output

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://slider.kz/#unravel')
for i in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a'):
    if i.text != '':
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

output

```
https://slider.kz/download/371745468_456554892/238/cs3-3v4/s/v1/acmp/cOE3Il1BHU9ESEFr9Hz4pL7WfYMASX1jY3IxqYGfVbDA7njmXutAbM3kHNfpwOzSBQWa2IZQ7huupcnHjAdwPgptzXqreGX0tmqzvcVCEsQn7_VVdO2neH6DlOB61uNtIBCcnHAMlApXwBfbMccaKZDif1_ZPf1e-4rkVEyHP9VQBiCGZQ/TK%20from%20Ling%20tosite%20sigure%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499200_456477539/242/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/68YuXV09VzsZx8eNd_eKHNOjhjlx7Ae93T9h6eA4wjSJruGLjWdJqvGRkKfvEla9GYPHVopebj2BMYIsTf9R2a5-ztCHImKELMaUZQBuM1_OtyVbt2_AxQqxfs9ziB-1F1_vSJ2wJQO8EfhsuQi8Ouz-qH5nyqJPMAaPhuKuqeJ7XDdIew/Anata%20No%20Senin%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001620886_66620886/237/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/9F7u-H32JUQGkAjlBPuZTbwaM2ZkjLchrhJxmqDZjIODWGIF6ClRnA49X4_rMHf5E8b9SPQUJqKtEwS_4cq1EkwDf97msqqps6gnKzAwJRNU7lhLkaJ6hqd0yZg27uBAvK6wMpizrt3HpGUIuURFmYDMWX7ggp802aWW51gkn_rQOAE0Gg/FalKKonE%20-%20unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499141_456425057/270/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/sD64r4KNC9Ye4CfOMggOFmSA-ric7pUSKLaN_bfGIArMK7MSwjhu4lHpICSxWKCDniNKGTOOiGcg_6b6VUfLRuvSzn-Cakp4YU2BFw-5DJ2KAlFf4Duz6txtUAen3mslUB-vOSV8mT48PYf4VuoxFkltIb-kYqzkXgvsr56GGrXFzYo54w/Dima%20Lancaster%20-%20unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul%20OP).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499133_456468907/240/psv4/s/v1/amp/I4gkKu5n8-ePABgx_5blRV5izpZRPdm6o3_5C619b-f0tDciBsojh2EkLvtQ3xref_TYPVL7vBktamf1mdxDmxi3xZz1XC_HKAwsjUqU03dJpvytOBXsiCZ6kgP2FQ/Yung%20Anime%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001476389_94476389/229/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/A6FBXBqjCCmhlytjFG4rAKFNfD78JTsqzgNAZToGubFqSZ_t1OQ_4gXhqO9qxFs3nPX2V6u745hB34NMrpGSvAEEKhfV0u5jYjHKeAdqBTbp05hvkdg2aJ6lJMFO3gjA9DZjanfjDL1fjhDC02e50HYr-K-ILhQkjdrixmzi8Ed5PQJfXA/Nika%20Lenina%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001355458_97355458/244/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/ZRd1eY7d7KVAi23V-pkv91B0rBxyH6TBawtgTp0u_agc_1WbMS1061fhyFRFye9GHrUcaKX2KI1HIEzV0SXmJbSgy3q86HHZq08hTiwHdE27YVaxwn2HqW0r_AmOLtPMt6EcSNjcRyKUc-8sPnJ-PYKIPGeHoF67WUBsDbBteD1LjaG8fQ/TK%20from%20Ling%20tosite%20sigure%20-%20unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499285_456610507/236/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/yQ75TttqYQXX7TBSoFeRrACN7JTw4pDVbn7gQ0uYHgKyUtvarViLiz47siDjWti8wr-Udt9pYektb5tp-VY68B-nFSq8SQ1Amqo3YCROcOFMhfA-xxT__aZOT2eLjyC_8KqHeLGi6Dzc-Jo52P-30wiWCh09ScW4t8rmQGjspFzDuWMkqQ/Yung%20Anime%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499192_456485073/91/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/CnNkh81L0geRARmPlCx6HDtwarMIshv51_2gNlOHnFHKfJ3sTWbOXjzT7-SBqMmIMIusJ8lRN9tsjx4djCww8g3zd5n-x8SxDVVcMxhXKx-XqtOdT1q88mABUQhKY4ZcLos_XBYe7lx7C9CzcBabYFpBYZRZ-9x9M-HX52DfvajtnggW5w/Yendorami%20-%20Unravel%20(Opening%201)%20%5BFrom%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001941575_98941575/185/cs3-3v4/s/v1/acmp/fmdPR0KKIvzX-evg6umhtRemEihc16Hc0s0W6fanPFxDNR8vTeCaTGdId8L20cp4r43dNQO3XYNbdp4ftt0mwIxb89SFMmcn5bBMZCymCay9cegxcXx4dDhc2329j0Evv_KSB3wpIzA5IR9cBf34DyOdDkd6L1b_ygIpDGF5E1_yp4acPA/Collosia%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499243_456360717/225/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/i3ZW2FQYrSPIkVmjzhKxasRpNU2sHQA24dwNyYtNb7SpQTg9bTqGlKbpeknyi2-z74quCFgDKR6Vox0JFmyJJVHQmQkGrPxTgnngADz-Iaxa4q3MVUAJqzTZJgu32Ur-FRa3n-lcN3wy/Trinthepianist%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22)%20%5BPiano%20Version%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001187532_103187532/144/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/NuVJyRij62WtsZrXRq60T7I1G8mfLu-Q01ITWVXxnn9DvIa9hiRGNUfMX2HF7qJMNv6nLC8GzobY8nmh71W9ulIpnXI44tGkyBKcy3lyAq1rTpBjLXssQiC94zA07P238siyirG99-EQsSAFL29rMcG8UYN9hXqC5g9-Xc4hyhT5vuNsHA/KinovariSquad%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499138_456497179/330/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/OClerb_S3_yMpf46bD6zx0ObnCHcC6OQTPnK5Pry3qn8XVTOSLd_xRzCzUodFJoaLYbrjnKNHktd_J6PZu2m1hkZM3N--UNOqZkPIMubcOCJfcBBloN5BoCve2WvgftZ3yWubFzzWHiVpLnosbeogAzf_bMpblrewEeJ0-xC7toQeGTJ6Q/SLSMusic%20-%20unravel%20-%20Slow%20Version%20(From%3A%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001343575_62343575/235/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/O6pRAZYWRIaUHjj-3d-I7wDamPE2M1MziJsmpF1XKCPGPbOKR3UV_A5vqtpbBqPSPochs34hpYKTTsHS5eAL_FiKJwwKvbUFqD3exRAAbDouMGxfW7YEpmMkN8NcpVz5QmH0lEJypGWO84b9cRnPSB8ZAkWNyKpGue26FP9Qc-jFLAj6Kw/Geek%20Music%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499226_456421440/235/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/ErptzsuuaoawWhx_finD4Pb5GRbG05r7PrMIQy5LYmfw9QfJqjPBRGK-vRTrZnbsfSKoCA8K0odPCNvb_3rC3Mv-97bmbyv188pzC2PIKET0DntUvYYE__cD-KCVTnTyUpx3M5fe5hNdYjsb9UkYVngGlSBMNrA4OQhrp3-15Fybbvrfsw/Geek%20Music%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499206_456447563/243/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/Ll3SqtO1lm7C2W7j7T6-bCEZ03fOS_MAFwvXUqzizClbi3AJS4LYDddyPM_iI531Tv-t1hUYKQFeJCUsF9MCM_ox93UUSaP_M9Zp0uVdB4PSpBXcu6xgqoKCDkbQ69CcnGpARuXxeZ5XPo6hJox-8xvMuZnfoT_b76BasOFB7rcYjFPDsA/%E6%AD%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E7%8E%8B%20-%20unravel(%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%3ATK%20from%20%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%99%82%E9%9B%A8)%5B%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AD%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B1%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499222_456568196/98/psv4/s/v1/amp2/G5Qoz-PWlD8w86QFGNvVLmXfps93Kv7CVsbbVFpo4e5LjDQRJ_yuY4Ha3Nrp10xVXf5hur40alIvROP88ncZTLhPICCjkBn3mM7QGpaFgBQf3SEib-JCMELaZoMg36gpsc6vdsRKzSqjecjnhDAvjkixFTc05wTyL3b7/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Winter).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499266_456496174/238/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/ZSnEUsWBGhnXj5XDpV5_RYtliMXOCl747j9MfPXEJut-jDHGl9lI3z-Wyrmo1fnrb7QYMdmCyCFGChtLb_Jlnhj47w9llLDSfOeT-ejt6HrEFCVeG9pSJfb1x2Orv9ls1AWiprtX9TBylxyJYkTTMCT8lXPxyT_1Lhh63I_Vclx__QWHAg/The%20Unknown%20Songbird%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001091207_65091207/243/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/KQtj35XBV_qATTaJDm3ULd5piLxC8bhqrobCvIFfHM35M5YDIBlSZQyfTvcmGktv5upmL40wFiQuX65il7CSkTyvGgCubXJXch30BTk_8VgSnOQitmFNebJzW_ADxbaBwFpJsZRZ1La5UKahLdafzttj-qiWjk7B9uuiI2PejUViDS7oGQ/Bibi%20Gamino%20-%20Unravel%20(Opening%20de%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001815387_86815387/189/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/ao_2H9LXIsXS3wGH47_DjS8MTmTGiH8wBvOjh7ZTyXXT6gGCzwqO9j3fW940H4MSUnTlarmjLDf4kFN9izLPboP6opybIVo1zv0efcOASrk03xIjwIFbsZuB7Ub1vpl_U9jevxKne9xT7-8ecNhrm8_MrrcqEt2yUw6ApNIIDiFIjnPm9Q/Baur%20Karbon%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001343001_91343001/91/cs9-18v4/s/v1/acmp/zwfryFVsrFggm-hEVOd6RiXeyEUooW9tZMLBrntNjiPJOxatNavKMSQ6tdcBDb5DfN-5oz89p6eXNd61Td00hMgQXQ3pfU_uRhQXPtSNRXH26a_vH5x1z6VVndmwxWikty-kmyuctXkSLygSr-__9qnxcZYaNplAvE79Hl5maQC14zIq3A/Ren%20Avel%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001459950_102459950/222/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/dXsMP_kZ98lEdBVsmwcSr0zvYGcr5Spyn8RNNVYxfMDehWA3Jbcq7BpGMLoaKcgCMpQ4PpHszAAC3bkW4wNbKiFD6LumIhx0_T2C2xekVJsfR1xb8cVtOgwLUMFnffOWz3GULiHXBKoPS2xjpWf1TmkQXdDhcpmKqokCzhx0yvKBagDO0Q/Jonathan%20Young%20-%20Unravel%20(Full%20Version).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499249_456500220/95/cs9-5v4/s/v1/acmp/kI7HhI6sOV-jdnMnoifzOJwbZwidKai2LQ6nQOuVeZ73W2eyOcQUDIDLEuDWL6qhNZM4ATnhITDeeI1W34s3kaY03Bf9CGzRm2RTJHtIbF7U1ZHL5GJ_lKj8DR27Ulz_4whswvN7p4sUAuL8LHEyYCFjLrgQVlLTb_xfVL9j7q5_4ndF5w/Tony%20Gu%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22)%20%5BOrchestral%20Arrangement%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001472007_90472007/95/cs9-2v4/s/v1/acmp/D25FbaAzhvubfYuHGk82DiPeG6gHBuhK6YwgRt3UV2gnf-s7ynvbhcNomwhgm7kqj6RZ5cqVRgRhzUIVCLvLPjnuChQiPRefKOp8IH35ZjCBLRB5-CWFnNKMc2Z3Z_jQzeyxzikPI9PI5u9fErheiCWVb0HnR5k8FSg_guhCQaOBeYKgbA/Radio%20Control%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499153_456452837/238/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/QOuii-Czus3bM2CyRJILUYMWsCNb-6TEgDNKyBO_qJYdxeoLM5YEqyW03di_3mSuFpbTNqCD8cEN8ijmtjMRESRZCKya9Wj89Hyo8A6s7oQFURgmc0OAQw1ifU6FNPgNuLt0cM8UuVu5ONMZcXLxQB_X-vyVga9enPIDvzadwIPzMLrkKA/Kevin%20Remisch%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499122_456591314/97/cs3-7v4/s/v1/acmp/lOsM3wtU0cPI-POYId2zCQKMuFocZYxke-zM9kGXjLh_HWnKmpt9FT_BoUqdG_QMSQyXfnUdjzt11bJW4Z6hkc8izzQ_xo7UA70AhMVu2Ik-d5INvNV2W7xAbavVROqzFEPxMEmmYpazITlYQEy07UapD3KiFWUY1WRDbr_-1v30o018GA/Lil%20Bubb1egum%20-%20unravel%20but%20is%20it%20okay%20if%20it's%20lofi%3F.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001077985_82077985/238/psv4/s/v1/amp2/VllxAjiDhUD2kGGN_1QYYlEi6ljH-VawyGBR5t7gRwmBd4bnyoy7Q9TP42q83gu6qs0Q3xjHT7HEgi-HkPQAs3w417-ESpSQGMQEySHxg8O43I_0gt0dJ6edsjnIsWzRIrOtSJwBSeqtoUKitAfdgVRjP5-6egt8gLqr/%E6%AD%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E7%8E%8B%20-%20unravel%20(%E5%8E%9F%E6%9B%B2%E6%AD%8C%E6%89%8B%3ATK%20from%20%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%99%82%E9%9B%A8)%5B%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B1%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499138_456433311/238/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/VNdbMoXjNPrw1jhq0upwNnZfbolEFriZNKeUEHSf1ncOJUmACaSbyYEZiu1N8JghIVspFPzHWO3STGmE0lGuFvgo0bF6Y74ykyvwwSiDgcRqMbUBbn2ySHSA5RSLN8nCinRGvDvJ-5YSbYmvgZbwaNVWVFVJ0R7D4gwA5RPvt7BQj7eaeQ/PelleK%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001778472_74778472/238/cs9-2v4/s/v1/acmp/z1oe_35fnQwSwR-yAjBnQ4MlCd2PNIEnRSLz_ZCKF_5PldV40_lerssvNhZazYLx7YpdpVjqm_HNA8PIuAqrlvKioKNyrOu3GL048jLLCz_xJL38tDuU22qmn8mhf5YJ7_XzQygG4tmjHFh88hASl-wYpTowxw4kmOAcS0perZf4inwKbw/senakisaragi%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499220_456599167/246/psv4/s/v1/amp2/ZyCoku2jGfwD1BaUlyq7-q6TDH-IwTCPHDVoyJSz9TRj4hLvzyeFs3j5um5duLh8mru1sc22DqkxA7Ajara2-Y9GKl7PomX_F88WidLCB1MARvkw2iYrizN-q4Et4QsAWJm2VaSamp1vRDksmw5SUgN4a74Qh58sRx2Y/Matteo%20Leonetti%20-%20Unravel%20(Japanese%20Version)%20%5BTokyo%20Ghoul%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001804556_66804556/238/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/gIyB4Vft-_97FyJAE9_0hQlav32398RrusRMOaXgEkSsoBNW93224d76-9tGbFvAT07TSJEwetYGewbka3fjyJfSui8-paQTAJMVI5lMtwgMuTU9e6fB_cRtlIsXuN6vZhQORVl47To-JGxYgfN1-zRNimSOEBj4Ve_p121ne1UwhTnDLQ/V0RA%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul%20OP).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499291_456568508/102/cs9-6v4/s/v1/acmp/fKvZmSOyvLXOxRXgOatLErO-EzVCD2cn-tB1Dys0NFpugNtd7A4hZlhBPUZMXAKZIevqS49l2ZAscFh-k3RRHX02kgrbPM6H6AhcAZ_jbvNstSTtxywJvz68KeUWJ5y0Bp8ll3fL7g-rNSYGQEzIxoTjQ6LXqfB1eolI4ZUsqC8vUfoRcg/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Fall).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001227120_98227120/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/cLi6IzWrhQhwJVpx-nbHAVgRnIxbVTGQQZfcqBf1JyjYIYi55BhiY6bc_fFMdWxKV5lMiYXFcAbUTzrketBr5NXGs3a4B682hU58z4nXP-E3AET0RRFi2-zBVQkK8zeHEOfBGk4-RH8HbJvY4f_oJHfeSSfhVPyxOKdg/Olga%20Scheps%20-%20Start%20Anew%20(from%20%22Unravel%20Two%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499232_456549884/90/psv4/s/v1/amp2/G_D-kC0LEQYYW7ekPdSMg06ozpZssPpm4_4ke1P8RhdHN2a8EH0t27UjRhyBw98-veAur6NiLRcicS9vp4nzOPQIsqaPr_-v-x9h8m2L3yIzpDcVKTftL2Th9rB_H4g4tHTUl8orsWQU6npEA7sTWysshIwpFs_nqWQq/Mary%20Antoine%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001667855_68667855/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/xznk6i9L8LRfJar58xq3PjlC8dSayqHAQnXP8JIbQTSUFF6dtmf4AG1_Sr7dR-6gYxW05dzwebqzJJU-KkNJvqu6ieBiK_trxotPhLkBA3mmBcskTm8z1q6VnpE3YPOYyiJIOFl_NLvxbdT7GqlNW1UYnKScRVumta8m/Track%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499146_456450407/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/wEP-qGrwzxqR21c80CCBheBmiu2fIZVI4VsGd7CuyGxTkVI1boxILGBdheTs6tX0N6XCuLO1j4bAs5B8XGAmAEdD9ijXYGTW5cOYDQ7psn31PqmHWKubTdiefBdP9ztaYS6szPgmhtQ9FN9OoKKOH3-WWs3qW_IvYAFM/Track%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499318_456592131/96/psv4/s/v1/amp2/1Ngs7lG1WBh6TJ1IhzauBhSNBeazCty_k25JatXLvLqpadvgBgoQ0lY9ISeBhfts6PV2hs5QtYk9EZFXczQq7GVshKDrg8ovPv0OnPTolvNdOhhJjLiKPoF2dUewl09LW4yvJmX5ogCX7q_Pq-F3bWeLpa20NankBa_c/Vangakuz%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499173_456432829/137/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/rT3ABEaA8kmBYfjWSUgBN1i_wGr6c7BO5YQXfOdt474aADbZ0Tjg4OWB08dgPLHIcx6o3-rRRELc59NKPIhWhfVQq8jatvyFzxR6k6bo-wp5dJFVptg21nj7NTtWPOMcgvjXxblmVfZrXtZKGKCfFoqb-sO2sDKOM3prAMESLmk_HQieCg/Kenzie%20Smith%20Piano%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001400485_76400485/187/psv4/s/v1/amp2/wQrrOm95FEb1EpWPN05KTxkNgjEfDh_faLEMRAA1Qk4F4cCJSO_9sd8XjDlc714dR_OK9JyY_9AQCe6moPsLeNnM6iCbXzFZrdWObICKCxggwhxuCtyaM4liHWk5TgNcFC1GLQp8Lu7Hh8v2yiC062n2nfsvZHjenrho/Simpsonill%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001521828_57521828/551/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/dZXnCT1fUfJ6PdA2mzGe8yHpA9s-DY_9UYw3SUYt3z_QoxPkXt6m4epU3ilm_7hieMGGJIe-HQeq6UYmj1QZYvJPezdSZyd6wBiy288Zdv2zwMEqQsWrKziLnBIDpenTzJfh8Lht97PQ4hqkQ7mOGO8ucyZm1evH5kQFymrzeFQcstVf5A/Alveol%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499237_456436594/88/psv4/s/v1/amp2/8Bo41ZWBvHso221zqJhGjyABsxjNh8o27U_XLhVWL93AEuMhcNxyhU2Ur43TuL48o6nFZQDF5HpQj43ra3EM0ddi_ptqUCJRgVr1vF5ADTqFXYlzqdIO_Jg64Vku2kEfVPwd5KYOHoJD_VCsRTFN83sW5epkBJm1c798/MattxAJ%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001915683_101915683/90/psv4/s/v1/amp2/QaH-avVk5DSEc-4Xw50z0JX3TZLUGZ0nk4PblwUkmscM8QYZh2u6t8rFGB7D_GzbyTwxltM4Rp0kE1x0WfCO_QHO5IHZe047S93z7D2a_-DEnr8v_bwDtLv_10NQRabdX77HE8h9iWlSs_doa76LQMm3Gm6fYtCutX29/Music%20Legends%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499272_456394915/236/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/WDQwU05V9M89alMuCTi786gxWCQDoeFFwYlNzojOyQ5G5oeCmgknrMPfQGlX1dE1nn-JHFfaJOOhgXQJWptsR070hN8OufTiDgs4dzg43TzgDhi_Cn6mXxnfAq3qK5xDWSY4Kamlydi4hVH6xcC5uRrpy70lK5xEce7eq01yornEDvVkcA/Shiroku%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001529426_101529426/255/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/yz7am2kIPxn76UUaQEQFAeOfeTQciBwOu8g151LzAMMKMQ5NRg6nI92UZBjPePHnH9rV7svs2udN-fiGIpg2s8QqIbP9lWCyG-J1qUB9CywlXwu8tfg6CzSTN2GgbRp8iQM-QKlGrRgLxi56Up3r0U7oWubLYL0hEOKr3ysemG_9tB_Q8w/HalcyonMusic%20-%20Unravel%20(from%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499176_456433059/241/psv4/s/v1/amp2/EZVr_Le7Wnc33wId8JajbbOo03wZBaoT8f8_ZyHVTiL5h8hs8HtGSVdm3BLNaW_AH5znzjmROfyAYYPoYnLQ-pY789RfVtTwX034IVdl_tM097Dube-bzIGaa_7COKBlo3Dp_1lHWfn1EjrgHEI3YhYPhnVyxOjkRsrd/I%20am%20Justice%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001621142_58621142/68/psv4/s/v1/amp2/Oc2oMY7m2oW3hfpZDQIW24g3lWZIUDD1idJn8Wn5ZN5LJy29qZTBNwcHYCcxvtLPz5YsK4hWSvi71bW03O1eKw4PhvRXcqWreiPMJI9BJsHU6vwjXk1OieqMk3zC-stJLo5ZRIMxUpuefWK8HQlv7HfCAqrba3PI1_yG/Gianni%20Tallone%20Della%20Cavallotta%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001052300_100052300/89/cs9-11v4/s/v1/acmp/jENDq0_xjfWlA1Fau3Cd16w9dQT3Won_n8YIMUI3daFMPE4P3PEuYPxpnn37TYSDXtZsXjyDSPLFO2HbnzGi3yDkvfePGfIrY2lK4y19tTEY9Y6aRUZIbAN5eS-IWG91t19G8soWuPs8B09mV82_4lj6lW3900E11hWClLA-Xl7jCoN3bQ/Fonzi%20M%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/474499157_456624310/212/psv4/s/v1/amp2/WpHC4MCzE7o7pBv5lzq2K9K3pf4fZPUgW_GycJUP-92L5fd1yNx9fOLzJol5M9F5Mkwv8BApcjZkjLw4nC75G1rX7bnR-oZNOBP1pSw0EgJZi1o_a2soIKK3YLTMmcHdcdxXGNTJ3IG0YasN9w9n_8pzlc8mYoQYkOf1/Love%2C%20Lies%20and%20Fiction%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/371745435_456449924/271/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/2vGBvFG1ejsCoSv88vOr1JwaXPjPCw6aFRXBB_8fqa1j_LxgWXH7bzy_9JbcymQd5ACAr1bYoLnwBwfthYgqYHMWaL2DGTCu5Lp67BHZXWHRyGFeD3iKM5OeKLh4642GtJSGxVkgApp_9cRCvvIj-sRUAI1a0jgd_zjfAafM8eE8pf8WTA/The%20Blue%20Notes%20-%20Unravel%20from%20%22tokyo%20Ghoul%22.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/download/-2001260329_90260329/94/cs9-15v4/s/v1/acmp/9QTEytbysHCNmBriy3cvC2OOMqLUBoFMaUgslyo1b_QU4KGSKxWTJ-1x9bmqlxOIaCKJKTrsStWyE01pTlyCUU-tImpXxgFKyqcdpwQOvNAtLT_jiCrxmVpKGGryMeOgDp7xqcsbwWrDTqUYh685cY_Gc4avJ7va_QDg935M6qq_TxcxIg/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Fall).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz/#Contaminated
https://slider.kz/#Excarnate
https://slider.kz/#Extremity
https://slider.kz/#Serpent%20Of%20Gnosis
https://slider.kz/#Petrification
https://slider.kz/#Skullsmasher
https://slider.kz/#Hissing
https://slider.kz/#Mortuous
https://slider.kz/#Skelethal
https://slider.kz/#stabbed
https://slider.kz/#Winds%20of%20Leng
https://slider.kz/#Usurpress
https://slider.kz/#Encoffinized
https://slider.kz/#Glacial%20Tomb
https://slider.kz/#Overlord
https://slider.kz/#RESIN%20TOMB
https://slider.kz/#Descent
https://slider.kz/#Hurricane%20Death
https://slider.kz/#Gutter%20Instinct
https://slider.kz/#Crypt%20Crawler
https://slider.kz/#This%20Game
https://slider.kz/#LIFETAKER
https://slider.kz/#Autokrator
https://slider.kz/#Vanhelgd
https://slider.kz/#ATARAXY
```

How do i fix this.I tried randomizing my user-agent but the same result.The website doesnt have any log/sign in.

```
Chrome version 98
Python 3.8.8
```

Comment: when I open this page in browser (without JavaScript) then it show only `search` field. There is no links to download.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: @GreyMurav the site is up and running

Comment: @furas the links are extracted using selenium You need to search a music and it will have long list of musics it is in a tags and it has href attributes which is the links given

Comment: I don't see selenium in your code. You use requests and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: this page load JSON data from https://slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel and you may try to use these information to create links to files.

Comment: i actually cant scrape the the url it scrapes the main page

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. As I said: page uses JavaScript to generate links - but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` CAN'T run JavaScript so they can't give you links. JavaScript get data from [slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel](https://slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel) and you my try to get it and generate url to files. OR simply use Selenium

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: at this moment I see other problem - at least on my computer - server has problem to send any inforormation. Event in browser it shows `undefined` instead of list of links. And it has this problem on Firefox and Chrome. Maybe too many users try to use server at this moment.

Comment: dude  got another problem and good news. good news the link you gave has the url but the link slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel returns an empty list while printing soup.find_all

Comment: as I said it gives JSON data,not HMTL, so you don't need Beautifusoul (it useless with JSON) but use `response.json()` to get Python dictionary with all data, but it gives numbers, names, etc. which JavaScript uses to create links - and you will have to use these values to create links. BUT at this moment I get only dictionary with message `error`. Maybe too many users try to get data and it sends error.

Comment: oh i also get the error json maybe tommorow i will try. Thanks though if you put this as answer i will upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to download data and generate links. But `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

You may try to find url which use JavaScript to get data and later use it with `requests`. Usually JavaScript sends JSON data which doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`.

---

Using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) you can see URL which it use to get data and try to use with `requests`.

It gets JSON data from http://slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel but it gets numbers, names, etc, and you would have to compare with real url to see how to use them to create real url.

At this moment server sends only messasge `error` so maybe too many users try to get data

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel')

print('text:', response.text[:100])

data = response.json()

for item in data['audios']:
    print(item)
```

---

It gets also other JSON data - `similar artists` - from url https://slider.kz/similar/artist/unravel - and it sends data without problem so I show how code can looks like after getting data.

```
response = requests.get('https://slider.kz/similar/artist/unravel')

print('text:', response.text[:1000])

data = response.json()

print('key1:', data.keys())
print('key2:', data['similarartists'].keys())
print('key2:', data['similarartists']['artist'][0].keys())

for item in data['similarartists']['artist']:
    print('name:', item['name'])
    print('url:', item['url']) 
    print('image:', item['image'][0]['#text']) 
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
key1: dict_keys(['similarartists'])
key2: dict_keys(['artist', '@attr'])
key2: dict_keys(['name', 'mbid', 'match', 'url', 'image', 'streamable'])

name: Contaminated
url: https://www.last.fm/music/Contaminated
image: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png
---
name: Excarnate
url: https://www.last.fm/music/Excarnate
image: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png
---
name: Extremity
url: https://www.last.fm/music/Extremity
image: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png
---
name: Serpent Of Gnosis
url: https://www.last.fm/music/Serpent+Of+Gnosis
image: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png
---
```

Comment: as I remeber `_ga`, `_gid`, etc, are used by `Google Analytics` (to count visitors, etc) and you can skip them

Comment: Ohhh oke but how did you see the comment I deleted it?

Comment: I saw it accidently few seconds before you deleted it :) When I saved my comment then I saw that you deleted your comment.

Comment: Perfect I finished the web scraping and now I can scrape music from it and download it

Answer (score 0):

If you use the browser inspector (dev tools - network tab) you can see that, every time you hit "Search" it makes a get request to this kind of url: https://slider.kz/vk_auth.php?q=unravel

The response is a JSON with the results.

So, if you want to use requests you should get this url and then extract the information from the response JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working.Please just run the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://slider.kz/#unravel'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#driver.close()

for link in soup.select('div.sm2-360ui + a'):

    url=link.get('href')
    abs_url='https://slider.kz'+ url
    print(abs_url)
```

Output:

```
https://slider.kz//download/371745468_456554892/238/cs3-3v4/s/v1/acmp/QRhl3TT5g1GEHPv-bkQJXT4UPbfj2OAAOI01kg3IFGV3PQUawPjulWC4U1oquAFZgADZF4QaOxk8CrEfBzLih4EpJf2a8qTr3WYT0yJQiCNDV78tnhuZAGmi1p2I4wwdw_743Rfe6Y9lvMXcVHwnKd7NdRyUlKLz5XxjVAUTGxP17pY_qA/TK%20from%20Ling%20tosite%20sigure%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499200_456477539/242/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/AsZGD44ViRPS8iviU4fbOjb7I095Guqb8LMt4EBRZEwgTYR2BFlFAI4HtLEu_JTeohwHwakRgcJ9pnUurkL98oL6co9QTzepES6zqJ_tDYp4oUN5D3E5pm-m2LZGkqeCNcLsZmA6PeuxNSkpEvbfnq7W-in6XtIpASiP9qQ1UdSb1wXIgA/Anata%20No%20Senin%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001620886_66620886/237/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/gOSXhnJZc_7qVqSRt7soH679KeuB1qEa_Odx7P2YY9BwEAbmB9L2N-j8Qcm2roEWAxA-45rEGOQ1KT3r6CxnNYFZKC6t0Gg0J-wIjnC0sfDNhJrQpogT_kHrV7rhUSyFPLq6mrP3A7Tj1Dgl_KzZdjB-REw-21XuVyxlrLIgQRJiApQ1vQ/FalKKonE%20-%20unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499141_456425057/270/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/9l2EX9ERaANRDGCKW8RS4-_VZR2MZYDlMRLy-cTAlKW4SP7QsodWeBObK7VaJa3vQiD7DOC6YEdOxTZHUUUksY6Xj7l1OgMyaJ1uzDLiVxtTy7NfJ98tdknxtnDhvNk3gXnoTZI5Fhs18fSDusmQkFAcDYkC8A7Czpng3gLvsvtoHQeQjQ/Dima%20Lancaster%20-%20unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul%20OP).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499133_456468907/240/psv4/s/v1/amp/84PrmRmfu7EBaFB3FMcMuLy9CrIgecvqzu74ZHTGdBVyhe1rQRRhSBfVA56cHNnwSPP4GNXVvQ88IZJq0exhcN8Fvn5k9rIdI-PJWu8QviAWxX4aYZqon1Sflf1Cbg/Yung%20Anime%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001476389_94476389/229/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/YRjjyO0TiBxN0blkh9T8e-6g6SepkCtdIMtBqNLYvHbfqOCYLBqpvwS6RmWXLeYNUKMy_FutPbQ9LLRPSHFO-TYBQwAM4AoT6Z5_vvSepusrUJu33dDVYMAIWntUc8ABhjmnLRfVPeBbHYzGnx22n2Je_U15qYFD1we3aWiaw2qV9CxbTg/Nika%20Lenina%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001355458_97355458/244/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/f-WX05d925zpwPtfj0RS6oUftizqO337PogbUWwnM1M8hsXNV26bPGdtEgze2yNpsEQygL5qeip-xc5s7LBFOtY5X_4n0fQo-oWz9vkdRvD3sUl9XEPgibbUob0VFJ4itJXtm1l1D1LRHTyDcNeA3xDj2S2n1s_7Bi59L8RpZgIGWmvtcg/TK%20from%20Ling%20tosite%20sigure%20-%20unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499285_456610507/236/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/QMrplAB509ufV1tZgQn756q7IsLtpEmITRyaCLzQBrMEFmK-Zc-IkEWdOI_eE5D4-Nz1i2Y97wu7cmlF69HxYWPqjcp-2pWLuUzg4h1YeOUtTGh-nteiMEdfnpJYfYkyP6ZwayqLFLOh7OH0Ki9n3lNYRm1A_U47zVi-lsRS2IGOCZQAOw/Yung%20Anime%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499192_456485073/91/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/ukuxjLP1ByDVop0pyoGvFwd4eQTFJnLH_6Dod2uT9uR9VCLHcTk9zoKqes1bAAb7bM8wDj1VTxi_ooy8I_AcNjW91hjWhb2uKMBYow8RR2WciYlyJ2ndYfqcBHwTOH_bj4fd1nPng0AFGG7phKNleCZW0tg3tlvzMjTHPKfsOI3w-Rypug/Yendorami%20-%20Unravel%20(Opening%201)%20%5BFrom%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001941575_98941575/185/cs3-3v4/s/v1/acmp/kLoq7G6WCnnVNV4gIOaTAA0sZWVTO34BChRHQ-SLhB47bp0Fu3ogijAaADtrwsqaZlKDLkY6RwLlAf8f-hgIGM9TCJ11mwzLsnIOc9YJRkDeUYH74GT2WF0tIO7nlPGg9iv2dVFDld089JM6-XcbT849iJCegdNGQ3qSkcaFjrQ1NaJFbA/Collosia%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499243_456360717/225/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/N0jZrOAfPu-5bJlwP0HzVU_8yG96Xddn12wE1QMmBOH_3aza1-ig-cHZHrY3dx76Ahm8ppqKO-uYXOCNAYUEK_mPy2Uy6npKbUlnRKn-YHIze3gP0IRvLHaaVMCACfEx3W-srnsSQTiN/Trinthepianist%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22)%20%5BPiano%20Version%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001187532_103187532/144/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/TYPoa8_kCxJuIGNUL1Wl_5vYYnxcl0CrUNYlv6FzMCLCgRyI5TrNjhX7xCuuRFBsSxGeTDX8rqI8acAvhNSGX0u__Hzr84NWTzMp2rtgee6NyN793lVcVF7r499W_34RTTC6exIIGcYEIhwUxDMC-BBwIQr6pYnBctsAbVJYd4ZcD-2JKg/KinovariSquad%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499138_456497179/330/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/_WbB2KC7ZDs22xTYAFfwRyk0p3GfbW8L-q9exF4raO5H_YnoX1rdRmAGXSW9xQCk_7sxBLfA-WO0UT0ilQVPRVwo9GR6upY8VLlMWyRHtntEaNOnUakzaiUBcTIE5mGRYs3ti5Ek1JGmhtioUBPEr94GVtrOMeKGRPe4s56oYHWlO3xXrg/SLSMusic%20-%20unravel%20-%20Slow%20Version%20(From%3A%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001343575_62343575/235/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/6pYoGLam7Gpf2Urd4PDhHInGLa0NZXgC4MiBNBCE_PG-YBTqjPZiIJNdgJty3HEEA42N4htrAN0TyudLT_l0rASk3yvwH8HSSl1GEA7xTxy8ZuQ1BfLrpHwIZ6g9MY2saaMmwaz51K32mUtBQHKXltyWuCvWzwYteRs3ZwuOhyEES2AJFQ/Geek%20Music%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null        
https://slider.kz//download/474499226_456421440/235/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/ZHspQ1RQdnss3kdW6LREudZe1CVOFo2wItlxVeppU8SDGGPmfoVUH1p4451LnaaNG61RtRDrZD46eBfoTGwdmsiXmZ12Fzyhg_A5UMGplsTPHxOcL9Pw8CJ-VTQlIEwNiLJKwoWXxKIZ0e4h2A7rq3hRs49qnAzIc3lRE93yzrLCymc0ng/Geek%20Music%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499206_456447563/243/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/26YcSjZs2EOKlDmgk6YspYb5imv6RXR1NsTkMBi6jgJMvdf5nNX3vJLWO-z9YAxl97b8JTxF3HK_u5wT7TcQfiIcFHOoLvXM7jg_Y1YMW1Vlc-sj-kqadoXFbGw_x9aI0NzZIT-VpYncsYC6N0N3cQsi_UjPPgHT5iiuIvFW6JHFBm5ROg/%E6%AD%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E7%8E%8B%20-%20unravel(%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%3ATK%20from%20%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%99%82%E9%9B%A8)%5B%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AD%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B1%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499222_456568196/98/psv4/s/v1/amp2/5MdAXyMQXscyhnNEfxrNMz4rZAhA3Ckw9tV0tLA94BDtvVCeDVz_Ycc62dFPtyJvjDaucoWBQZAguZHmkHV81InGjY22Am3TtoTYWH4rGOoiaM8coOi8DpIUQd21gda6fFcTZMkuLf0t33P5it1dH86nAmDGduot9AYu/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Winter).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499266_456496174/238/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/GkaHnOLSSRydiMt--oHvxPF2ZrdnAK-NO5Lei7J48RoxS_io3XwVnMFTQJN54MLZ5oagc9cSb4COMi_yxoCuAEm4FMnA3Kqetj5cj5D_alBQkHJEtNHS4IL1-kgE_QQ9RDsAfu5Qq2GrdyXj06rpvRr1EyKs1ITAkPez6uvlHAozli0mWQ/The%20Unknown%20Songbird%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001091207_65091207/243/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/izDJAIBhtw7Gbo37AL4HCeFiLWypB9BgtdIqUnziUZ06PBBWt6OVqGY5BJIjaY4E3fG1szeoZcQeU7946ltUPsX86cPyq9jMfaPTbNS2rk4qaDYoJtK70qlGrA_OwvHUS3Ec_BQTFNq3-fqv2tJuyElVIaUesQOo4MMH7BpaTUI1T3n-BA/Bibi%20Gamino%20-%20Unravel%20(Opening%20de%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001815387_86815387/189/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/1q3ZcWs-DyWh-iYHwleI-jAD5A1WVgP8sN0zolnoNmBaj55OQqmHopLzZPd7AWmYP2Xs6E7Tv7BDtGn3TU1_-cDD13sbCywSWwQB2ckEsW84uZKn38qj0vcbYCN7YqDp7L4-drmoSdzIyHRE6xXrixB9cJuXgcKlTbSwkFh7-HRoU1lA9g/Baur%20Karbon%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001343001_91343001/91/cs9-18v4/s/v1/acmp/pk4LPfaKgfokG8pHZAzxFPGhpemNTcIw-Ey_8BN1RPX_QNtv9m7H5HzsrKVY-b2p1_AKiSm_jJOdWV1iUXGsjtOF-mkjo4er3adDmZSFB6BqlCGQgXkK7F1Kn8XQDc5dc41KESB5p-JTSPKOCzitje8M8wcsdELenOJANNsvKtByjHRL6A/Ren%20Avel%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001459950_102459950/222/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/dOeaiW4FJ3Q0jfOOTinST8c8Pn59ODRoRT5BgYrmn-DJw7m-u3x--lLPiUeECWRcHc7kKLGuAKoVTMUt32QfU0RDeGRCBGV2F8V8MPzNNczL3Qk6GQP9Bpj4ZL7SUUWlINmeRZyDChuD1APnUZtAzQ31DhAkQgpCH70MMHmtl6SNLNCVCQ/Jonathan%20Young%20-%20Unravel%20(Full%20Version).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499249_456500220/95/cs9-5v4/s/v1/acmp/Cd6m3qhcIfjSesLIbaLc8IPOVc4E0H9ljKh_VIlj5LcIDifka-qMXBDquBCwd16bV2an-ZGX9X_NFFyV32q5DOg6AEKAMrSOdWQl9EC_mkvCLX1RLBF8HVarOoMZ9Y9oaV-gDNO9iTstvL0vBGQoxYz-CXIKok5FOfC5ptoG3dfSsRwkmA/Tony%20Gu%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22)%20%5BOrchestral%20Arrangement%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001472007_90472007/95/cs9-2v4/s/v1/acmp/sqXJVOoZTIZvRB2CxjUHJZdvYHeaQkVffFqfpn4SW39S1-lImykJzWyENkb2tWUMO9eZNnOwNR0a6eZWPKvrBKdpLzLQE7JJFvV9kxKu8h2inNFyhSazlAljMtC3cn8R5Wk1B0uQdQY-17wb6-oBb7qoGSeiIBT-7C_Ob4G-JXcJ_6EUJw/Radio%20Control%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499153_456452837/238/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/IQdnnyJQZtLM-cx27JQiYpqw3hrvc7Y4LGbUy5ruMBZNzC-7Bb4W6Wlw3M5CLykxFM2ALSU-aPR2xyMvggKW4gtqeXIhyfOq4yQbFNCYgG7mXXwwHp18FeyDTkXdYbdCbOZ05gQpO26e54LFLEky3FaAwvy48gQdHSUBAlCDNFN7gNUoMA/Kevin%20Remisch%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null      
https://slider.kz//download/474499122_456591314/97/cs3-7v4/s/v1/acmp/05S842jqQXODQOr-pq-LCi3z3CKmZR-6f9sqWNjGrXOaJDf-Ga0F42wMYDQmLTtChJaCKz-4kIdgGTXL-unYs4sJd3cg7ZwbywsPL2lMS5CiseljaXJ5I960mN1frRnZV-jVMiNqASMWfF9m5COgxgS_IAEvVDW5_tiXQxMxDfp_JSygOA/Lil%20Bubb1egum%20-%20unravel%20but%20is%20it%20okay%20if%20it's%20lofi%3F.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001077985_82077985/238/psv4/s/v1/amp2/TJu-2VmMhrc6VA7SF1OM2092kq003sX40joJxtIzXgAulLrdmWnzcVDMjn7L-dp5oXZVnqh-tXxyEbY-20YIvqOOWOuYlnldJHceTYDII9aJM-JhsA_Y9jkdCSOKZ0lwp_OhCWGFKEbfHu3NBJanFbms4EdBFUhNQH7K/%E6%AD%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E7%8E%8B%20-%20unravel%20(%E5%8E%9F%E6%9B%B2%E6%AD%8C%E6%89%8B%3ATK%20from%20%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%99%82%E9%9B%A8)%5B%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B1%5D.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499138_456433311/238/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/CqmMRJm5B03c3so1ex1GshI705Z472EzHgAWm-M9eznXzjVF_6G-7lYlhkHdfPpHsWcVU6hWhLRqVr6WrYKBXcyvZ-ri0q5iV9Jv8Iwyd91t9cLu0sWVP1W3016tZKK0CSoXyfiL_oOfFhHbF9DbqmjmyUVO9ZB-McrQY6PlmOk4M-MBHg/PelleK%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001778472_74778472/238/cs9-2v4/s/v1/acmp/26oh4w3DDMsrZziue-jJNLoL_DKv7JMHYjXTixs0K4KjVjP0V6qTG2t5nmh6H9e8DVf3PH6Xoeqq1nzN718lXcKkSuutTFbWpgvA1nmV8M3DlQvm_WXyWRMReTYLwSwmwpALZ60-VbutNMFN3l8vPJ9F7lJCyi7V2ncQu9KxyWMCRD5C1Q/senakisaragi%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499220_456599167/246/psv4/s/v1/amp2/SX9vu47zGi9Uos8gQWm7XbfU1l0EKA1jqYblOj3ePK0pl5yPWLNFqITGYWgpzA1sRw6DzP_RAzgnu0C9-b2Ej5NDF4gU0px6dVSeOvO0DlKeW6XGcy2jFMJJCjHB_ag1VXEJgRb3jUYZLYRItNORbxOd45tRox8MGKBm/Matteo%20Leonetti%20-%20Unravel%20(Japanese%20Version)%20%5BTokyo%20Ghoul%5D.mp3?extra=null       
https://slider.kz//download/-2001804556_66804556/238/cs3-5v4/s/v1/acmp/SGrWKb-wUFGqKV704k_bMGD7EJHh_A6sw2C9D8sWzWUA0R956jql_ZlVKEMv0MsJQ8gFsacMt_tywv3ZeXisu-rGTn4j_E8T3HS-o5RaqLzLOJauSlPoidthk8eIcx5xy4tGURb4KQkIfwIFJhriTy9HlnR7vCbaPpj_PfVNTBdlo7CU2g/V0RA%20-%20Unravel%20(Tokyo%20Ghoul%20OP).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499291_456568508/102/cs9-6v4/s/v1/acmp/44hsI7dzI30x7Ho7N20vnYC06nWK2Sx-iXDPJXyN--Coele4vZUdekMfyNazmGRQ3IYMnLr1XBMPRWLVqZFkzHLk4fa_H5JN85IDDtft8EGPjsBRpSJOmbiAVAodQwQw3JcF6LW88ajmqKtJh3eUYARn9vrfQVN_J-ODVFY-dYm_akXUmg/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Fall).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001227120_98227120/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/s57ppy-s9vm4n3qy-y4h8p4l0f5XyxK38-d91I3odmc9gvabMD_t42h8zd2oRL49tQkR1CD_vsPwIRA6DHsRUuW2WAkGJVwcef_VBmXUGsw7xEJSJG8kx-9AIXAUlj-8Ot32vMWg4TCiy/Olga%20Scheps%20-%20Start%20Anew%20(from%20%22Unravel%20Two%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499232_456549884/90/psv4/s/v1/amp2/-eUtSpHonW9PPES9zCRzzNYbTSu7i_AEVujmMuifOKCuYme-q6vqFR5fXVHik2ARsaGX9_x4Za45VNNZohqsdkdCToDbne2W_6P7zgqnPJSuosGi8Z4ol0h0V_ViLH1ZIw_meOnJOkFDOTjKKyF-Ol0IvevzfvqPJtC0/Mary%20Antoine%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001667855_68667855/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/IwKjMHOHdlAXWq1z1B5qxNBGhN8JVmJy-pJEl_b3RrTdZrGTPB_U0KIkNnnq7NcP5e1wa5ms9jSB1LIhEdiZTN6c7PHTMyJaLxNM8TDA46JpfBIXy73o11mf_FyBbAjkOIevfweKBRPukNSdConEqZr2ZUQoVaFeT7ZK/Track%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499146_456450407/186/psv4/s/v1/amp2/NMuGmiwJOxvdnOKQLkH0gIvMLbj_I_b5UIivo2Q2qVIxnI6kkJ5ITkC9rtL3H-28k3P6SzP-SEiegRZp_CyuXtuxPOA-qcx8Jo7VJEu817oIipyKTLFF9TBnMa6_E7w4Fa9uWM7RhR_J0VBAdPCDE4hi58gKNRBJ3bl5/Track%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499318_456592131/96/psv4/s/v1/amp2/zVQkmtvUwnxkcZxoMYAgcJ-RBoo8WvzKV6PyKAif3fw1C7fr-rzaWQbimUXK7_xSaKfsZpokZ7WRNdLOzxWm8QP8rlG2NNHYNQv6b2OmOiqOpP-WqeQ3VRvHN-0FtzcWnjYsIJZKcLcBA_q89U2c9Otw2Bqcvbt4lxRq/Vangakuz%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499173_456432829/137/cs3-1v4/s/v1/acmp/_LgsM2-WTNOvaV85Hy6ObbzZSKnJNfppdaWt9A_NyTv3XYhfSpyJ3QXFyQDb8nISAoRbTgNEt4yXtvvbWDli7gClVqaNCdiuTpEIwDl0EUZqyUF_aJrueZAjvd1DdUJR0YhvL6Fmv5C-8KoGEKotgiL1Eq1O4hU1wFDxayNVb4TkOzwwEQ/Kenzie%20Smith%20Piano%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001400485_76400485/187/psv4/s/v1/amp2/TFqk4JfH34feLtswrYZZXKfFUtIfXRTq8bOmXxLIHX99vXnkmPTp_A6-Rjj8fS9qiAQ6ao9F-VQvLZSH0bAnjBiUCM8pZbtBsL6z1v38vZzsc3kpP21MYG6kBCtfqg_jJhlj4CqDmfvQ0nW1NoUSNmutLvFy_7KTyjVG/Simpsonill%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001521828_57521828/551/cs3-6v4/s/v1/acmp/kXLXCQe33bHi2WDA_-0y9UGNCgbK7Xhca4q6pig_COLFf5bNaN11Z-4Kzd3A9tanob-U9_Jni_Ix5beoPUaJurH1ozqI6XQiKuHPmkxkLKRSXZpd_tj6SQhkniNDwxBxyRANOsxVfbHe80fcXahF0OWTKc4R5mjB1L1XVLsOhILcdpyS1g/Alveol%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499237_456436594/88/psv4/s/v1/amp2/yha2bLmL0XLvXvjfVKdqa25-JSAeZQYu8QQKRZKNwVAINm3912ZetkeVDrvSt5MeOyyto6x-PvbwC7hiBAXKC7g8_PwbcXKcqmku8hiHr7xJKl9ca34WIzeqNLyayp9RcFxGjO_Gk_AuaQ0ZBgXTaChq2nE4OTl1bqbX/MattxAJ%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001915683_101915683/90/psv4/s/v1/amp2/E79KiQTMA5b8mthMlpzYU5TRFcns8aqBNzqvKDFGJ14IR9Cz_C5yChPQUPQW-VFAm9_8sbo51D01NENhaegDJJIyui36C5ECVDwGaLhOcoLrhB8RKPLBGDLN01fcrb8mIxb7t0MhWr_YefPgj4Zt13xlufjor89n84eg/Music%20Legends%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499272_456394915/236/cs3-4v4/s/v1/acmp/2LiycWJnJntKnyikeZn_7TLKdSb8v343jFSIXZ9dbhcnsbSsjQZvlUI0jBkPWRGwGp5cK7UdprZarl3TUh_e_j_0vPrQs1SRHyogfbJlfQuM54Tr34iFNBasQLHCmZv1ktctdpEmuwNm4Yj2yi_1wLs9Iwqc9lBaZ-WmbDsfeeayQNwOLg/Shiroku%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001529426_101529426/255/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/em6rSRlSNNcJHpGpiuSV4-VjdhJoAsemcgDXdS5VPu3XYPF1y-45PleMXDNAZ8jNEkf-5V9h7AInOtxaLBiP8KcWDvKW5d6EVy_hhh_qqK4PgpSPLS5Kv6yhdh7gUy2vo0t-ZVt-mZcQ1-8k48Q58_JE2U4JRD2ZgV8yVVbXKAK92bDnqg/HalcyonMusic%20-%20Unravel%20(from%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null       
https://slider.kz//download/474499176_456433059/241/psv4/s/v1/amp2/ATyS1Qxr7uBxM2KN4G0dMynLla7gPAaTh9nkDH5fMGYBEycOzy3sfM8LmLIjM2JP5yO3Vml0jBuTpeLoY9BBFCcWaD4qZ81dHjXsWFddJdyXqK0lkV4aKOo8EbMdyCJwRzeCesqn3r4aa_Pvxp3f6oPzLQgubvIXUF-s/I%20am%20Justice%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001621142_58621142/68/psv4/s/v1/amp2/CL5J0kD4Xm1iSLFGqD7zrODdTqubYTFwGCzC5r1n3Z_Tu6G_68RtjH3HaEY_D8qHuckrW0C0bCfUD5fXz0gxfoJD5PtEGwPpi_wQUdGi-D7dJITBjyMxx6dWz5duvvqZ7dmmW7ydKBGGaxHPI9_tofxRB_qqQmop_I11/Gianni%20Tallone%20Della%20Cavallotta%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/-2001052300_100052300/89/cs9-11v4/s/v1/acmp/IvCOhCCclMK3tCeswQwVtNhtyYHX5lgjJUZfQsCfskiHciXLjBpj9SzjZMop3u-kPRSuyeyFvJoJEiP-2z_owq5MPdx4uNgrbl5Mqm0xbC_JWlpl4VH8Sc_vdNn28SHpU6EJiWDKgN7kf_sRozvO5OCEq7YmcfQe2lC_awFHsJV0KU7rHg/Fonzi%20M%20-%20Unravel%20(From%20%22Tokyo%20Ghoul%22).mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/474499157_456624310/212/psv4/s/v1/amp2/-oLu8sAswnvZ-I4RRXNqDu59CLZGoMUsv6qNVAL9QTVO9TcP4SWmGmUJSgfiXAw-_MgjRO1Y1y90YBuAirIcJgFenZe0XxlsqWrtbr6CEyQypX3sfmidTTBcH91G2x-4dXiDLI6JUmSXR9vZ4KQ_Z4vl-9o8SbiPmdD8/Love%2C%20Lies%20and%20Fiction%20-%20Unravel.mp3?extra=null
https://slider.kz//download/371745435_456449924/271/cs3-2v4/s/v1/acmp/ased-v3q4z-i_oiBH_OoVrZntdBkQGYKVQre0wr9DyNB7KVvbXTnpHh6G0_EyuBf90j3bW9SbB6aUeTt8NgAKKiuezgzETKKXzUhtpacQuKQEo-upEFNHLq5VzSrFAz2IjSSA3lm-p9plN7U4DQOPnCzn1_klu8Mje4uY3TCcwoTAuPckg/The%20Blue%20Notes%20-%20Unravel%20from%20%22tokyo%20Ghoul%22.mp3?extra=null     
https://slider.kz//download/-2001260329_90260329/94/cs9-15v4/s/v1/acmp/qI5QjSZzHW-fYGXdVihZndt972zUCvmUN2Qzjk9gfUgyTjh_XPeOh9ctff9Ob2ezMEbFLEL7oNkrnvgoh4EJy9JlUjJPhTQS2Fh3L1cLzqJELD-waEz9vDaZwS_IuPXr0nH2PO5img_a4xkkqRLIy-VDm64EVAdGelBPmwLf7rIj_qjF9w/Piano%20Cat%2C%20Anime%20Cat%20-%20Unravel%20Tokyo%20Ghoul%20(Fall).mp3?extra=null
```

Using requests module from api

```
import requests
import json
headers={
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
api_url='https://slider.kz/similar/artist/unravel'

req=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()

for url in req['similarartists']['artist']:
    print(url['url'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.last.fm/music/Contaminated
https://www.last.fm/music/Excarnate        
https://www.last.fm/music/Extremity        
https://www.last.fm/music/Serpent+Of+Gnosis
https://www.last.fm/music/Petrification    
https://www.last.fm/music/Skullsmasher     
https://www.last.fm/music/Hissing
https://www.last.fm/music/Mortuous
https://www.last.fm/music/Skelethal        
https://www.last.fm/music/stabbed
https://www.last.fm/music/Winds+of+Leng    
https://www.last.fm/music/Usurpress        
https://www.last.fm/music/Encoffinized     
https://www.last.fm/music/Glacial+Tomb     
https://www.last.fm/music/Overlord
https://www.last.fm/music/RESIN+TOMB       
https://www.last.fm/music/Descent
https://www.last.fm/music/Hurricane+Death  
https://www.last.fm/music/Gutter+Instinct
https://www.last.fm/music/Crypt+Crawler
https://www.last.fm/music/This+Game
https://www.last.fm/music/LIFETAKER
https://www.last.fm/music/Autokrator
https://www.last.fm/music/Vanhelgd
https://www.last.fm/music/ATARAXY
```